# creating circular link list the compiler stops working

Tags: c

the compiler stops working ,pls give me some solution

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
typedef struct
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
}node;
node * create()
{
    node *p;
    p=malloc(sizeof(node));
    p->next=NULL;
    return p;
}
void add(node **h,int ele)
{   node *temp;
    temp=(*h);
    node *p=create();
    while(temp->next!=temp)
    temp=temp->next;
    temp->next=p;
    p->next=temp;
    p->data=ele;
    (*h)=temp;

}


void main()
{   int ch,ele;
    node *h;
    h->next=h;

    do
    {   printf("\n1 add 2 delete 3 insert at kth position 4 delete at kth position");
        scanf("%d",&ch);

        if(ch==1)
        {
        scanf("%d",&ele);
        add(&h,ele);
    }
    //if(ch==2)

    }while(ch!=5);

}
```

Comment: Is it too much to ask that you format the question properly? Some nice person might do it for you out of (i) kindness, or (ii) +2 reputation gain, but don't count on it.

Comment: There we go; kindness.

Comment: @Bathsheba  Just an enter :)

Comment: So what's the compiler output?

Comment: Do you get errors when you build the program, or does the program crash (or otherwise stop working) when you run it? If you get build errors, then please edit the question to include the actual, complete and unedited output from the compiler and/or linker. My guess, though, is that you have a *crash*.

Answer (score 3):

Like I said in my comment, my guess is that you have a *crash*, that the program stops when you run the program, and that it builds without errors.

The reason is that you are using the local non-static variable `h` without initializing it. All local non-static variables have an *indeterminate* value unless initialized, and using those variable without initialization leads to *undefined behavior*.

The solution is very simple: Allocate memory for a node (either as a normal variable or dynamically) and initialize the pointer `h` with that.

Most compilers are actually capable of detecting problems of this kind, but since it's syntactically and semantically legal it will not issue an error, but a warning instead. And if you don't get such a warning then you need to enable more warnings.